# Can't hear headphone sound with MSI MAG X570S Tomahawk Wifi motherboard

Tags: sound, headphones

I can't hear headphone sound on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with the MSI MAG X570s Tomahawk Wifi motherboard. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

MSI X570S motherboards, like the MSI MAG X570S Tomhawk WIFI, are totally supported by Ubuntu currently.

See more details here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1954628

The fix that worked for me was to run

aplay -l

Then, look to see which card number "USB Audio" is. I think it can vary when you reboot or plug in USB devices. For example, if you see this:

```
card 1: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]  
Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Then it's card number 1.

Then run "pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:X,1" where X is your card number.

You should be able to start hearing sounds at this point. If you go into Ubuntu's Settings/Sound then "USB Audio" (not Headphones - USB Audio) should be selected for output. If you reboot, then your card number can change and you have to repeat the steps.

If the above works, then you could also try using a command that finds your audio card automatically:

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:`aplay -l | grep "USB Audio" | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1`,1
```